# How to view the current keyboard layout on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, keyboard-layout

I am not using any Desktop Environment (GNOME, KDE...)

I am using i3wm and I mapped the alt-shift key to toggle fr,ara keyboard layouts

I want to view (from terminal) the current layout to use it in a bash script to print FR or AR in my i3blocks status bar later

both these commands do not change the output when I change the keyboard layout:

```
$localectl status
      System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
          VC Keymap: fr
         X11 Layout: fr,us
          X11 Model: pc104
        X11 Variant: ,dvorak
        X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle


$setxkbmap -query              
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     fr,ar
variant:    ,,
options:    grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration#Viewing_keyboard_settings

Comment: same output for both kb layouts

Comment: Did you try some of the other tools listed there?

Comment: yes I was hoping for some native command, it seems I'll settle for one of them

Answer (score 2):

use [xkblayout-state](https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state)

```
$ xkblayout-state print "Current layout: %s(%e)"
Current layout: us(us)
```